# Android Studio unresolved reference. Project compiles

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, unresolved-external

After upgrading Android Studio, a project with no issues started showing issues in the editor. I have lots of `Unresolved Reference` errors. Anything under the support libraries (support-v4, support-v7).

[image]

In the screen capture above, anything showing in red isn't resolving and showing as an error.
I am also using Lifecycle components and Room database. They seem to have issues as well. Looks like interfaces can be found but classes can't.

For example, in one of my classes using `Room`,

`android.arch.persistence.room.Database` and `android.arch.persistence.room.TypeConverters` resolve correctly, but

`android.arch.persistence.room.Room` and `android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase` do not.

[image]

Note: The project builds and runs fine on Android emulators and devices without any issues. It builds and runs using the build button on Android Studio without any errors. I'm not getting any Class not found errors. This is just an issue inside the Android Studio editor. I have already restarted Android Studio, cleaned and rebuilt the project.

Here's my project build file:

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.70'
  ext.serialization_version = '0.6.2'
  ext.gradle_plugin_version = '3.2.0'

  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx" }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-gradle-serialization-plugin:$serialization_version"
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx" }
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
  roomVersion = '1.1.1'
  archLifecycleVersion = '1.1.1'
  buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
  supportLibVersion = '28.0.0'
}
```

And module build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 28

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.project"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true
    kapt {
        arguments {
            arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas".toString())
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
flavorDimensions 'version'
productFlavors {
    live {
        dimension 'version'
    }
    dev {
        dimension 'version'
        versionNameSuffix '-dev'
    }
}
buildToolsVersion "$rootProject.buildToolsVersion"
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
  }
}

kotlin {
  experimental {
    coroutines 'enable'
  }
}



dependencies {
implementation "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3"
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:$serialization_version"

// Support and google services
implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-core-ui:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-fragment:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:preference-v7:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3"
implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1"

// Rx
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.2"

// Retrofit
implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0"

// Testing
testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2"
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2"

///---
// java 8
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:$archLifecycleVersion"

// Room components
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"

// Lifecycle components
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"

}
```

Comment: Did you try invalidate cache/restart android studio ?

Comment: what is your gradle version?

Comment: Restarting didn't work, answer below did the trick

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had the same problem. It is related with new AndroidX libraries and migration on it.

> Try File -> Open -> and click build.gradle to reopen project.

Comment: This actually worked. So weird, I had cleaned and rebuilt the project using Build -> Rebuid Project. That didn't work.

Comment: How is OP's issue related to Androidx?

Comment: It works! No idea why is this problem still happening in 2023 even with the latest Android Studio and no migration whatsoever, just completely randomly once in a while. Rebuild or clean project didn't work, you gotta reopen the project. Weird...So many bugs in AS.

Answer (score 7):

Please Delete the .idea and .gradle project from the app directory and Invalidate and Cache Restart the Android Studio.
This will resolve this issue.

Comment: A simple reload of the project did not  work for me; deleting the `.idea` and `.gradle` directories DID work!

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Stanislav Mukhametshin that may be it is related with new AndroidX libraries and migration on it. I had cleaned and rebuilt project but that didn't work. So, I tried this way and error goes away.

1) Go to `File` and **close project**.

2) **Reopen** the same project.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple Solution Is That:**

1: GoTo File And Close The Project.

2: Then GoTo File And Click On "Open Recent" And Open Your Project.

**That Trick Works For Me.**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Kotlin file that wouldn't be recognized as Kotlin and the files depending on it were showing errors.
Project compiled successfully.

I tried all the solutions posted here and also "Sync Project with Gradle Files. None worked for me.

I solved it in Android Studio by overriding file type by doing:

1. Right click the file and select "Override File Type".
2. Choose File Type > Kotlin (in my case).

Hope it helps someone!