# How can I remove unresolved references in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

To use android Room ORM in my project I added the Room dependencies in my Kotlin/Java project
and after `gradle build` I get a whole lot of `Unresolved References` errors *see errors below*

[image]

I've tried this
[Android Studio unresolved reference. Project compiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52811373/android-studio-unresolved-reference-project-compiles) and this
[Unresolved reference: kotlinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169562/unresolved-reference-kotlinx) 
but no solutions yet, 
How do I solve this *Unresolved Resources* errors

[image]

Comment: Could you add your sourcecode, especially from `CameraFragment.kt`?

Comment: i doubt this is caused by you adding a dependency for room to your project

Comment: what's your kotlin compiler version?

Comment: @MdGolamRahmanTushar my kotlin compiler version is 1.3.50-release-Studio3.5-1

Comment: @MartinZeitler my CameraX library is currently 1.0.0-alpha09

Comment: Just use the current version the `CameraFragment.kt` or use `1.0.0-alpha06`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler ```1.0.0-alpha06``` worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
1. Build -> Clean project;
2. File -> Invalidate caches \ restart and press `Invalidate and restart`
```