# Unresolved references in automatically generated files [Android Studio/Kotlin]

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I faced a problem with unresolved references in automatically generated files after refactoring/tidying up my project.

What I do:

1. Create new package `project/model`
2. Move existing `Account`from `project/accoutDatabase` to `project/model`
3. Rebuild Project
4. Receive Error in generated files: `Unresolved Reference : Account`

These unresolved references are all located in the `java.generated` folder and annotated with "Files under the 'build' folder are generated and should not be edited. The changes will be lost when sources are generated." Thus, manually replacing the reference is useless as the files will be newly generated when rebuilding the project.

```
Screenshot: Folder structure & Error
```

[image: img_folder_structure_&_error]

I tried the steps suggested in the following link, but they didn't help. [Android Studio unresolved reference. Project compiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52811373/android-studio-unresolved-reference-project-compiles)

Does anyone of you know how to resolve this issue and what causes the problem?

Best regards

Comment: you tried cleaning the cache and still have this problem?

Comment: Yes, I invalidated cache and restarted but the issue persists after the restart. I also tried first deleting .idea and .gradle before invalidating cache and restarting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found the error source.

When moving a `class.kt` into a new package `package.class.kt`, Android Studio automatically changed `import class.kt` into `package.class.kt` in all kotlin files.

However, Android Studio did not adapt the usages in the .xml files. In my case, the moved class appeared as a safe-arg in the navigation-graph.

The solution was adapting the appearances in the .xml file - here nav_graph - manually.

i.e. manually change `app:argType="class"` to `app:argType="package.class"`